# Excel VBA - Get data from Pivot Table using 3 row elements and 1 column element

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table with more than 11,000 rows of data and 53 columns. I need a piece of code that very efficiently fetches data from a particular cell in the Pivot Table.

This is what the Pivot Table looks like:
[image: Pivot Table]

I need to be able to fetch data from particular cells using the three (3) columns to the left as the conditions from picking the correct row and offset to the correct column by using the week numbers 1-50 at the top.
[image: Fetching the data]

Here's a snippet of my current code (which works, but is probably highly inefficient since I need to this query about 48 times right now.

```
Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(tWB.Path & "\Telledata egeneide YTD.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Telledata")
Dim pivotdata As Integer
Dim storeNo As Integer = 1101 'Example only - this can be anything between 1101 and 1199
Dim storeLoc As String = "0002" 'Example only - this value can be anything between 0001 and 0003
Dim materialGroup As Integer = 1120 'Example only - this can be anything between 1110 and 1899
Dim week as Integer = 11 'Example only - this can be anything between 1 and 50

pivotdata = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(oWS.Range("A:A"), storeNo, _
                                    oWS.Range("B:B"), storeLoc, _
                                    oWS.Range("C:C"), materialGroup, _
                                    oWS.Range("C:C").Offset(0, week), ">4")
```

I'm looking for values that are higher than 4. As mentioned, the query at the end needs to be run up to 48 times as it currently stands, as the variables in the code snippet changes.

**Example query:**

```
storeNo: 1101
storeLoc: 0001
materialGroup: 1141, 1142, 1143, 1410, 1420, 1451, 1220, 1260, 1270, 1710, 1720, 1730
week: 11, 12

storeNo: 1101
storeLoc: 0002
materialGroup: 1141, 1142, 1143, 1410, 1420, 1451, 1220, 1260, 1270, 1710, 1720, 1730
week: 11, 12
```

As you can see, all the queries have to be run twice (for each storeLoc), plus I have to check two WEEK columns (the chosen week and the week after).

I've been thinking about a For / For Each loop, but not sure how to go about that...

Comment: `Dim storeLoc As Integer = 0002` FYI `0002` is not an integer - if it has leading zeros it can only be Text/String.  How are those values stored in the underlying data - as Text?

Comment: Also, good callout on the leading 0s @TimWilliams. OP - you will also need to address this in my solution if you decide to go that route. Assuming your pivot fields are text then the input you search for will also need to be text (i.e. `0002 <> 2` as far as the match goes)

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be a string, sorry The leading zeroes need to be there, but it doesn't need to be an integer. Just got it mixed up when simplifying the code to be presented here.

Comment: In future do not add formula as tag if you are not able to use a formula solution. If you need VBA then just add that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using a dictionary lookup based on the unique combinations of the 3 lookup columns:

(untested)

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable, rngRows As Range, rngData As Range
    Dim dict As Object, arrRows, arrData, r As Long, k
    
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    
    'https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/
    Set rngRows = pt.RowRange   'get the rows range (includes headers)
    Set rngRows = rngRows.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngRows.Rows.Count - 1) 'exclude headers
    arrRows = rngRows.Value     '... get as 2D array
    
    'create lookup based on the 3 columns
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrRows, 1)
        k = Key(arrRows(r, 1), arrRows(r, 2), arrRows(r, 3))
        dict(k) = r 'link the key to the row number
    Next r
    
    Set rngData = pt.DataBodyRange    'the data from the table
    arrData = rngData.Value           '... as 2D array
    
    
    'now you can use the lookup to quickly locate the data you want
    k = Key(storeNo, storeLoc, materialGroup)
    If dict.exists(k) Then
        weekVal = arrData(dict(k), WeekNum)
        If weekNum < UBound(arrData, 2) Then 
            nextWeekVal = arrData(dict(k), WeekNum + 1)
        End If
    Else
        'no match found
    End If
    
End Sub

'create key by concatenating the values with "|"
Function Key(v1, v2, v3)
    Key = Join(Array(v1, v2, v3), "|")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising from what I can see!  I'll test it as soon as possible.

Comment: `k = Key(arrRows(r, 1), arrRows(r, 2), arrRows(r, 3))` gives me following error: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Comment: Did you copy the `Key` function at the bottom of the code?

Comment: No, that did the trick! :) Works like a charm now, except that it gets the value from the row below the one it's supposed to fetch from. So when materialGroup = 1110, it will instead search 1120 (which is the row below). Probably just a single number that needs to be changed.

Comment: Hmmm it looks like `pt.RowRange` includes the headers - made an edit to account for that...

Comment: Yeah, that works. :) Thank you. Now I'm just looking for a way to adapt this code to do multiple lookups. I already put this code inside a For Each to loop through each storeNo (a total of 63 stores) and that works as it is, but I need to look up multiple materialGroup values at the same time (3 at a time) whose values can be combined into one (for example 1110, 1120 and 1121 from the Pivot table's 3rd column) and I also need to do one lookup for storeLoc = "0001" and one for storeLoc = "0002" (second column, values must **not** be combined)... Getting complicated.:)

Comment: Difficult to come up with an optimal approach without the full workflow.  What is "best" will really depend on what you need to do.

Comment: I'm playing around with some ideas now. :) I think I'll submit a new question if I can't figure it out. The original question in this entry has been answered anyway, and this addition looks like it's too complicated to explain in the comments. Thank you again.

Comment: Continuation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370527/excel-vba-dictionary-lookup-in-pivot-table-repeat-process-with-dynamic-criter Have at it if you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Formula Solution

You can use `INDEX` & `MATCH` here to extract the value that corresponds to the row that fits your storeNo, storeLoc, materialGroup and the column that matches the week input.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$4,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$4=H2)*($B$1:$B$4=I2)*($C$1:$C$4=J2),0),MATCH(K2,$A$1:$F$1))
```

---

### Table Reference

Assuming a table (or pivot table) structure like below...

[image]

And a input table with target criteria like so...

[image]

*Depending on your version of excel you may need to confirm this formula as array. To do that, enter the formula and confirm with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>*

Comment: Very interesting solution, thank you, I'll look into this.  But it needs to be in the form of VBA code. Could perhaps use EVALUATE to translate that into VBA (?)

Comment: errrrrr then why did you tag this with excel formula...

Comment: Sorry, that was perhaps not the best idea. But your solution is interesting nonetheless. It may lead me in the right direction. Thank you for your contribution here. 

Comment: No worries - Tims solution will def be speedy. Much faster than a loop. You could recreate this in VBA but you might as well leverage the tools available in VBA (like dictionary)